# Gradle error when using Google's latest API

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, google-vision

I'm using Google Vision API's sample to make barcode reader in a webview of existing project.
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision/tree/master/visionSamples/barcode-reader

this is my error message:

> Error:(36, 13) Failed to resolve: com.google.android.support:design:23.0.1

This is build.gradle file:

```html
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.harry"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.support:design:23.0.1'
    compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpclient-4.3.6.jar')
    compile files('libs/commons-codec-1.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpclient-4.1-beta1.jar')
    compile files('libs/apache-mime4j-0.6.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpclient-4.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpcore-4.1.jar')
    compile project(':..:ExpandableButtonMenu:library')

}
```

when I created BarcodeCaptureActivity.java,
I get tons of errors...
BarcodeCaptureActivity.java:

```html
package com.example.harry;

import android.Manifest;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.ScaleGestureDetector;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;


import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailability;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.CommonStatusCodes;
import com.google.android.gms.samples.vision.barcodereader.ui.camera.CameraSource;
import com.google.android.gms.samples.vision.barcodereader.ui.camera.CameraSourcePreview;

import com.google.android.gms.samples.vision.barcodereader.ui.camera.GraphicOverlay;
import com.google.android.gms.vision.MultiProcessor;
import com.google.android.gms.vision.barcode.Barcode;
import com.google.android.gms.vision.barcode.BarcodeDetector;

import java.io.IOException;

public class BarcodeCaptureActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "Barcode-reader";

    // intent request code to handle updating play services if needed.
    private static final int RC_HANDLE_GMS = 9001;

    // permission request codes need to be < 256
    private static final int RC_HANDLE_CAMERA_PERM = 2;

    // constants used to pass extra data in the intent
    public static final String AutoFocus = "AutoFocus";
    public static final String UseFlash = "UseFlash";
    public static final String BarcodeObject = "Barcode";

    private CameraSource mCameraSource;
    private CameraSourcePreview mPreview;
    private GraphicOverlay<BarcodeGraphic> mGraphicOverlay;

    // helper objects for detecting taps and pinches.
    private ScaleGestureDetector scaleGestureDetector;
    private GestureDetector gestureDetector;

    /**
     * Initializes the UI and creates the detector pipeline.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.barcode_capture);

        mPreview = (CameraSourcePreview) findViewById(R.id.preview);
        mGraphicOverlay = (GraphicOverlay<BarcodeGraphic>) findViewById(R.id.graphicOverlay);

        // read parameters from the intent used to launch the activity.
        boolean autoFocus = getIntent().getBooleanExtra(AutoFocus, false);
        boolean useFlash = getIntent().getBooleanExtra(UseFlash, false);

        // Check for the camera permission before accessing the camera.  If the
        // permission is not granted yet, request permission.
        int rc = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA);
        if (rc == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            createCameraSource(autoFocus, useFlash);
        } else {
            requestCameraPermission();
        }

        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this, new CaptureGestureListener());
        scaleGestureDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(this, new ScaleListener());

        Snackbar.make(mGraphicOverlay, "Tap to capture. Pinch/Stretch to zoom",
                Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    }

    /**
     * Handles the requesting of the camera permission.  This includes
     * showing a "Snackbar" message of why the permission is needed then
     * sending the request.
     */
    private void requestCameraPermission() {
        Log.w(TAG, "Camera permission is not granted. Requesting permission");

        final String[] permissions = new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA};

        if (!ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                Manifest.permission.CAMERA)) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permissions, RC_HANDLE_CAMERA_PERM);
            return;
        }

        final Activity thisActivity = this;

        View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity, permissions,
                        RC_HANDLE_CAMERA_PERM);
            }
        };

        Snackbar.make(mGraphicOverlay, R.string.permission_camera_rationale,
                Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
                .setAction(R.string.ok, listener)
                .show();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {
        boolean b = scaleGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e);

        boolean c = gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e);

        return b || c || super.onTouchEvent(e);
    }

    /**
     * Creates and starts the camera.  Note that this uses a higher resolution in comparison
     * to other detection examples to enable the barcode detector to detect small barcodes
     * at long distances.
     *
     * Suppressing InlinedApi since there is a check that the minimum version is met before using
     * the constant.
     */
    @SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
    private void createCameraSource(boolean autoFocus, boolean useFlash) {
        Context context = getApplicationContext();

        // A barcode detector is created to track barcodes.  An associated multi-processor instance
        // is set to receive the barcode detection results, track the barcodes, and maintain
        // graphics for each barcode on screen.  The factory is used by the multi-processor to
        // create a separate tracker instance for each barcode.
        BarcodeDetector barcodeDetector = new BarcodeDetector.Builder(context).build();
        BarcodeTrackerFactory barcodeFactory = new BarcodeTrackerFactory(mGraphicOverlay);
        barcodeDetector.setProcessor(
                new MultiProcessor.Builder<>(barcodeFactory).build());

        if (!barcodeDetector.isOperational()) {
            // Note: The first time that an app using the barcode or face API is installed on a
            // device, GMS will download a native libraries to the device in order to do detection.
            // Usually this completes before the app is run for the first time.  But if that
            // download has not yet completed, then the above call will not detect any barcodes
            // and/or faces.
            //
            // isOperational() can be used to check if the required native libraries are currently
            // available.  The detectors will automatically become operational once the library
            // downloads complete on device.
            Log.w(TAG, "Detector dependencies are not yet available.");

            // Check for low storage.  If there is low storage, the native library will not be
            // downloaded, so detection will not become operational.
            IntentFilter lowstorageFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_DEVICE_STORAGE_LOW);
            boolean hasLowStorage = registerReceiver(null, lowstorageFilter) != null;

            if (hasLowStorage) {
                Toast.makeText(this, R.string.low_storage_error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.w(TAG, getString(R.string.low_storage_error));
            }
        }

        // Creates and starts the camera.  Note that this uses a higher resolution in comparison
        // to other detection examples to enable the barcode detector to detect small barcodes
        // at long distances.
        CameraSource.Builder builder = new CameraSource.Builder(getApplicationContext(), barcodeDetector)
                .setFacing(CameraSource.CAMERA_FACING_BACK)
                .setRequestedPreviewSize(1600, 1024)
                .setRequestedFps(15.0f);

        // make sure that auto focus is an available option
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
            builder = builder.setFocusMode(
                    autoFocus ? Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE : null);
        }

        mCameraSource = builder
                .setFlashMode(useFlash ? Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH : null)
                .build();
    }

    /**
     * Restarts the camera.
     */
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        startCameraSource();
    }

    /**
     * Stops the camera.
     */
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (mPreview != null) {
            mPreview.stop();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Releases the resources associated with the camera source, the associated detectors, and the
     * rest of the processing pipeline.
     */
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (mPreview != null) {
            mPreview.release();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Callback for the result from requesting permissions. This method
     * is invoked for every call on {@link #requestPermissions(String[], int)}.
     * <p>
     * <strong>Note:</strong> It is possible that the permissions request interaction
     * with the user is interrupted. In this case you will receive empty permissions
     * and results arrays which should be treated as a cancellation.
     * </p>
     *
     * @param requestCode  The request code passed in {@link #requestPermissions(String[], int)}.
     * @param permissions  The requested permissions. Never null.
     * @param grantResults The grant results for the corresponding permissions
     *                     which is either {@link PackageManager#PERMISSION_GRANTED}
     *                     or {@link PackageManager#PERMISSION_DENIED}. Never null.
     * @see #requestPermissions(String[], int)
     */
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                           @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode != RC_HANDLE_CAMERA_PERM) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Got unexpected permission result: " + requestCode);
            super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
            return;
        }

        if (grantResults.length != 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Camera permission granted - initialize the camera source");
            // we have permission, so create the camerasource
            boolean autoFocus = getIntent().getBooleanExtra(AutoFocus,false);
            boolean useFlash = getIntent().getBooleanExtra(UseFlash, false);
            createCameraSource(autoFocus, useFlash);
            return;
        }

        Log.e(TAG, "Permission not granted: results len = " + grantResults.length +
                " Result code = " + (grantResults.length > 0 ? grantResults[0] : "(empty)"));

        DialogInterface.OnClickListener listener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                finish();
            }
        };

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Multitracker sample")
                .setMessage(R.string.no_camera_permission)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, listener)
                .show();
    }

    /**
     * Starts or restarts the camera source, if it exists.  If the camera source doesn't exist yet
     * (e.g., because onResume was called before the camera source was created), this will be called
     * again when the camera source is created.
     */
    private void startCameraSource() throws SecurityException {
        // check that the device has play services available.
        int code = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(
                getApplicationContext());
        if (code != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            Dialog dlg =
                    GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().getErrorDialog(this, code, RC_HANDLE_GMS);
            dlg.show();
        }

        if (mCameraSource != null) {
            try {
                mPreview.start(mCameraSource, mGraphicOverlay);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Unable to start camera source.", e);
                mCameraSource.release();
                mCameraSource = null;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * onTap is called to capture the oldest barcode currently detected and
     * return it to the caller.
     *
     * @param rawX - the raw position of the tap
     * @param rawY - the raw position of the tap.
     * @return true if the activity is ending.
     */
    private boolean onTap(float rawX, float rawY) {

        //TODO: use the tap position to select the barcode.
        BarcodeGraphic graphic = mGraphicOverlay.getFirstGraphic();
        Barcode barcode = null;
        if (graphic != null) {
            barcode = graphic.getBarcode();
            if (barcode != null) {
                Intent data = new Intent();
                data.putExtra(BarcodeObject, barcode);
                setResult(CommonStatusCodes.SUCCESS, data);
                finish();
            }
            else {
                Log.d(TAG, "barcode data is null");
            }
        }
        else {
            Log.d(TAG,"no barcode detected");
        }
        return barcode != null;
    }

    private class CaptureGestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {

        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {

            return onTap(e.getRawX(), e.getRawY()) || super.onSingleTapConfirmed(e);
        }
    }

    private class ScaleListener implements ScaleGestureDetector.OnScaleGestureListener {

        /**
         * Responds to scaling events for a gesture in progress.
         * Reported by pointer motion.
         *
         * @param detector The detector reporting the event - use this to
         *                 retrieve extended info about event state.
         * @return Whether or not the detector should consider this event
         * as handled. If an event was not handled, the detector
         * will continue to accumulate movement until an event is
         * handled. This can be useful if an application, for example,
         * only wants to update scaling factors if the change is
         * greater than 0.01.
         */
        @Override
        public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
            return false;
        }

        /**
         * Responds to the beginning of a scaling gesture. Reported by
         * new pointers going down.
         *
         * @param detector The detector reporting the event - use this to
         *                 retrieve extended info about event state.
         * @return Whether or not the detector should continue recognizing
         * this gesture. For example, if a gesture is beginning
         * with a focal point outside of a region where it makes
         * sense, onScaleBegin() may return false to ignore the
         * rest of the gesture.
         */
        @Override
        public boolean onScaleBegin(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
            return true;
        }

        /**
         * Responds to the end of a scale gesture. Reported by existing
         * pointers going up.
         * <p/>
         * Once a scale has ended, {@link ScaleGestureDetector#getFocusX()}
         * and {@link ScaleGestureDetector#getFocusY()} will return focal point
         * of the pointers remaining on the screen.
         *
         * @param detector The detector reporting the event - use this to
         *                 retrieve extended info about event state.
         */
        @Override
        public void onScaleEnd(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
            mCameraSource.doZoom(detector.getScaleFactor());
        }
    }
}
}
```

why can't android studio recognize import in java?

I'm stuck here for 2 days...
please help me!!!!

Comment: Should be `com.android.support:design:23.0.1`

Comment: wow, how did you know? such a smartie!! but another error came up. "Failed to resolve: com.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0"

Comment: It should be `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'`

Comment: thank you so much Mark. However, I'm still having issues here. im trying to use barcode-reader in visionSamples to implement in webview in my existing app.
So I started off with adding BarcodeCaptureActivity class (basically copy and paste from sample) and added to my project.
do you know why android studio cannot recognize these imports?
import com.google.android.gms.samples.vision.barcodereader.ui.camera.CameraSource;
import com.google.android.gms.samples.vision.barcodereader.ui.camera.CameraSourcePreview;

import com.google.android.gms.samples.vision.barcodereader.ui.camera.GraphicOverlay;

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your errors are caused because the import statements are referring to the project files from the Github sample. `com.google.android.gms.samples.vision.barcodereader.ui.camera.CameraSource;` etc. all refer to files from the sample, which are not present in your project. When you import something, it follows the path down to the file name, so it's currently trying to find the file `CameraSource` by making its way down through the folders listed before it. These are specific to Android projects so you should copy any of the files needed from the sample project and recreate them in your own project.

Once you have them created, you can import these instead of the sample ones (i.e replace `com.google.android.gms.samples.vision.barcodereader.ui.camera.CameraSource;` with `com.your.package.name.barcodereader` etc. ) Android Studio will suggest imports when you start typing so it's easier to locate.

If you're still having trouble with it let me know :)

EDIT - As a side note, if you're trying to get an example Android project from Github running yourself, rather than copying and pasting (which can cause serious headaches) it's much easier to either

a)  Clone the project source code with git (built in functionality with Android Studio, see [youtube guide here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E0MjorpDWxc))

or

b) Download the github repository to a zip file, unzip it and then open it in Android Studio. (May require some SDK / Gradle fixes)

Steps for option b are:

1. On the github repository page (top level), click download zip on the right-hand side just above the list of files.
2. Extract the downloaded folder
3. Open Android Studio and select > Open an existing Android Studio project
4. Find the folder you extracted (Note if there are multiple projects in the folder as in this case, you will have to select the folder that you want. In this case it is visionSample/barcode-reader)
5. Android Studio will import this folder as an Android Studio project, and may show some errors if the required Gradle plugin / SDK tools are not installed (install them from SDK Manager)

Both of these options lets you test out the application much faster than traditional copying and pasting.

Comment: thank you Mark! now everything comes together and makes very good sense. your knowledge is a great help for people like me!

Comment: No problem @HarryS.Hur , is your issue resolved now? If so could you mark my question as correct, if not feel free to contact me

Comment: I just marked it, Mark :P so most of the issues have been solved, it was all on you man! I have one last error remaining (i hope) and I think its the type issue here. on "startCameraSource()" method of "BarcodeCaptureActivity.java" class, I see "mCameraSource" marked red underlined in try statement. I believe it has to be related to type issue. error says: "incompatible types: com.example.harry.barcodereader.CameraSource cannot be converted to com.google.android.gms.vision.CameraSource". and "Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'." haha... the headache is real!!!

Comment: Thanks @HarryS.Hur, I think you're problem right now is that you are still referring to the samples somewhere (maybe in `CameraSourcePreview` where the method startCameraSource() is) where the methods are still expecting parameters of the example project rather than your own class.

Comment: i think this whole problem is coming from adding .java files to my existing project by copying and pasting from github. I created my own .java file with same name and pasted everything off below the first line (package name). there, i got tons of errors because of the imports. is there any other way to re approach this properly?

Comment: I added .xml files and .java files from this sample project. https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision/tree/master/visionSamples/barcode-reader/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/samples/vision/barcodereader/ui/camera

Comment: I edited my answer to include options about how to use an Android Studio project from Github, option A is the easiest but requires git to be installed on your machine.

Comment: i used second method to open the project and it worked perfectly fine! however, how do you merge two apps? I need the barcode scanning functions from the downloaded app in my original app. that's what ive been doing for last two weeks. :3

Comment: I'm not sure if there's a way to merge them together (I've never tried it), usually what I do is to copy in whatever is needed as you were doing, having it working on your machine is helpful though.